# Does the browser re-fetch the entire react app when changing the URL in the browser's URL bar?

Tags: reactjs, request, url-routing

Using the router, window.location, the link element and also the href provided by react to my knowledge do generally not cause a re-fetch of the entire react application but only cause a mounting of a new component. Is that correct?

But if I for example change the URL in the browser's URL bar from localhost:4000/hello to localhost:4000/bye will that cause a re-fetch of the entire react application or does react somehow stop the browser from doing that by recognizing that it is the same domain?

And what about the behaviour of the browser's refresh and back buttons in regards to this matter?

Answer (score 0):

if you change URL by `window api` its refetch whole react again. but if you change URL by `react router` api its only change page components